# What is the apt equivalent of yum's createrepo?

Tags: debian, yum, apt, packaging

With yum, I can create a respository from a folder of RPMs with the `createrepo` tool.  What's the equivalent to turn a folder of .deb files into an `apt` repository?

This isn't about mirroring upstream repos or serving anything at scale, just simply taking a couple of built .deb packages and turning them into something I can point apt-get at.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several tools for managing repositories. The simplest one is `dpkg-scanpackages`, but a nicer alternative is `reprepro`.

Comment: reprepro seems to be the closest thing -- a bit more verbose than createrepo but also more powerful